# Calling Angular application not from the root path

Tags: angular

I created a simple Angular app with some routes inside. Now I am calling it from my browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/products_whatever
```

For this to work, to my understanding the following is needed:

1. Web server should be configured to return `index.html` on request to any relative URL. Index.html, i.e. my Angular app will inspect that local path, figure out if it is valid or not and decide what to do. Is that right?
2. What is the exact mechanism that is used to pass that local relative path to `index.html`? Is that some special HTTP header?

Comment: What exactly is your question? how to set up routing for an angular application?

Comment: My question is if my understanding is right and on how exactly this works. There is ton of material on how to setup routing.

Answer (score 1):

With this being your domain: `http://127.0.0.1` I will assume this is for local development.

## Local Development

If using the Angular CLI, running `ng serve` will spin up a dev server for you (you don't need to configure anything) and is accessible via `http://localhost:4200/` or `http://127.0.0.1:4200`. I believe `http://localhost` is by default a proxy to `http://127.0.0.1` and  `:4200` is the default port that Angular will use.

To directly answer your question for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products_whatever` to work. You'll have to change the default port to `:8000` you can do this by changing the config in the `angular.json` file or by passing a command line argument `ng serve --port 8000`.

You will also need to set-up a route in your angular app that will map `products_whatever` to a component.

**Angular Routing:**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SomeComponent } from './some.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products_whatever',
    component: SomeComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

## Production

For production the story is different. It will largely depend on what server your files will be served from (Apache, nginx etc) will dictate what needs to be done.

You may have to configure the server to re-route all requests to the `index.html` file and Angular will handle the routing.

Find out more about [routing](https://angular.io/guide/router) on the official docs.